# Meaning of # in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file, scripting

I am trying to run a script to unlock shared file. The script takes input of a file name and then run some commands on it. I am new to powershell and I dont know the meaning of #.

Comment: `#` begins a comment, so `# this does nothing`. But depending on your code, `#` could be used as something else -- you'd need to show it.

Comment: This has got to have been asked before. If not, shouldn't this be protected or something so future users can reference it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is used to comment out a line. Please see [here](https://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/a-cheat-sheet-for-all/)

You can also use `<# #>` to comment out multiple lines

Comment: Using more technical terms: `#` starts a line comment, `<#` and `#>` mark the beginning and end of a block comment.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I had experience of looking on / / or /**/ for comments. Now , I am also using # as comment in properties file.